# Display index of array that contains error when using Laravel Validator

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel's validator but I am having trouble figuring out how to modify the validator to display the index of the array which contains an error. My input rows are named as `rows[indexNumberGoesHere][indexNameGoesHere]`.

As of now, I am going about the validation very simply:

```
$data = $request->validate([
   'rows.*.title' => 'required', 
   'rows.*.price' => 'required', 
   'rows.*.quantity' => 'required', 
   'rows.*.discount' => 'nullable', 
   'rows.*.description' => 'nullable', 
   'rows.*.taxable' => 'nullable', 
]);
```

How can I go about using Laravel's validator to display a custom message to tell the user which exactly field contains an error? As of now, if the first title is empty, it returns the error: `The rows.0.title field is required.`

I would like to be able to customize the error text to say something like `Row 1: Please fill in the title field.`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the error are you getting?? Add that error in the question will be helpful for someone to answer the question.

Comment: @Senthur there is no error. I am trying to figure out how to go about adding functionality to a Laravel method

Comment: you can provide custom messages inside for loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass custom messages using the validator class.
there are two ways first to use directly which I am showing below the second is to use [form request class](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#creating-form-requests), you can add a messages function in there to have your message.

first import validator facade `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;`

```
$messages = [];
$rules = [
   'rows.*.title' => 'required', 
   'rows.*.price' => 'required', 
   'rows.*.quantity' => 'required', 
   'rows.*.discount' => 'nullable', 
   'rows.*.description' => 'nullable', 
   'rows.*.taxable' => 'nullable', 
];
foreach($request->get('rows') as $key => $val){
    $messages["rows.$key.*.required"] = "Row {$key+1}: Please fill in the :attribute field.";
    // Similarly for other fields ...
}
```

Then pass the validation with your custom messages.

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules, $messages);
if ($validator->fails()) {
            return redirect()->back()
                        ->withErrors($validator)
                        ->withInput();
        }
```